# Is it possible to update the formula of a model object while maintaining simplified notation?

Tags: r, glm, lm

I have a model formula with a few interaction terms. When I update the model via `update()`, the `*` operator gets dropped in favor of the expanded `x + y + x:y` form. This isn't a huge deal, but when comparing models via `anova()` (or elsewhere), it tends to make the model formulae less visually palatable, and changing the heading of the `anova` object is inconvenient.

The issue is that `terms.formula()` (via `update.formula()`) doesn't seem to make it trivial to force simplification of the formula (should be via the simplify option?).

For example:

```
# Looking for Dep ~ Ind1 * Ind2 + Ind3

update.formula(Dep ~ Ind1 * Ind2, . ~ . + Ind3)
##Dep ~ Ind1 + Ind2 + Ind3 + Ind1:Ind2
```

Maybe passing `simplify = TRUE` does the job?

```
update.formula(Dep ~ Ind1 * Ind2, . ~ . + Ind3, simplify = TRUE)
##Dep ~ Ind1 + Ind2 + Ind3 + Ind1:Ind2
```

Or the terms get re-ordered, and that precludes it from returning the simplified version?

```
update.formula(Dep ~ Ind1 * Ind2, . ~ . + Ind3, simplify = TRUE, keep.order = TRUE)
##Dep ~ Ind1 + Ind2 + Ind3 + Ind1:Ind2
```

The workaround I'm currently using is to just fit a new model, which is less convenient when the model call takes multiple additional arguments. Are there any better solutions to updating a formula object, while maintaining the simplified `*` notation?

---

A slightly clearer use case (full factorial design):

```
i1 <- sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace = TRUE)
i2 <- sample(c("C", "D"), 100, replace = TRUE)
i3 <- sample(c("E", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE)
i4 <- sample(c("G", "H"), 100, replace = TRUE)
d1 <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(d1, i1, i2, i3, i4)

m1 <- lm(d1 ~ i1 * i2 * i3, data = df)
m2 <- update(m1, formula = . ~ . * i4)
m2s <- lm(d1 ~ i1 * i2 * i3 * i4, data  = df) # Explicitly declare new model

anova(m1, m2)
##Analysis of Variance Table

##Model 1: d1 ~ i1 * i2 * i3
##Model 2: d1 ~ i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i1:i2 + i1:i3 + i2:i3 + i1:i4 + i2:i4 + 
##    i3:i4 + i1:i2:i3 + i1:i2:i4 + i1:i3:i4 + i2:i3:i4 + i1:i2:i3:i4
##  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
##1     92 121.07                           
##2     84 118.70  8    2.3646 0.2092 0.9885

anova(m1, m2s)
##Analysis of Variance Table

##Model 1: d1 ~ i1 * i2 * i3
##Model 2: d1 ~ i1 * i2 * i3 * i4
##  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
##1     92 121.07                           
##2     84 118.70  8    2.3646 0.2092 0.9885
```

Comment: Why are you fighting so hard to keep the simplified version? When you fit any model all those terms will be expanded. But the short answer is "no" when using the base R functions. You'd have to write your own.

Comment: @MrFlick Ok, that's a fine answer. I'm mostly fighting to keep things neat. Adding terms via `update()` is convenient, but it's inconvenient to fix the appearance of the model formula after the fact for reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`simplify` in `terms.formula` does the opposite to what you think it does. You actually want `simplify = FALSE`, but there's no way to do that using the default `stats::update.formula`. Here's a version that does what you want. Note that the default method has just been changed to use my version of update_no_simplify.formula, and the formula method just changed to use simplify = FALSE:

```
update_no_simplify <- function(object, ...) {
  UseMethod("update_no_simplify")
}

update_no_simplify.formula <- function(old, new) {
  tmp <- .Call(stats:::C_updateform, as.formula(old), as.formula(new))
  formula(terms.formula(tmp, simplify = FALSE))
}

update_no_simplify.default <- function (object, formula., ..., evaluate = TRUE) {
  if (is.null(call <- getCall(object))) 
    stop("need an object with call component")
  extras <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
  if (!missing(formula.)) 
    call$formula <- update_no_simplify.formula(formula(object), formula.)
  if (length(extras)) {
    existing <- !is.na(match(names(extras), names(call)))
    for (a in names(extras)[existing]) call[[a]] <- extras[[a]]
    if (any(!existing)) {
      call <- c(as.list(call), extras[!existing])
      call <- as.call(call)
    }
  }
  if (evaluate) 
    eval(call, parent.frame())
  else call
}

m3 <- update_no_simplify(m1, . ~ . * i4)
anova(m1, m3)
```

Output:

```
##Analysis of Variance Table
##
##Model 1: d1 ~ i1 * i2 * i3
##Model 2: d1 ~ i1 * i2 * i3 * i4
##  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq     F Pr(>F)
##1     92 95.496                          
##2     84 89.193  8    6.3032 0.742 0.6542
```

Comment: Obviously the output data are different because the seed wasn't set and the data are random.

Comment: Sure, no worries there!